# What's most important in professional world? Portfolio & Advance Skills or Grades & Newbie Skillss

Tags: professionalism, career-development, portfolio, professional-development

I am very much confused in this dilemma and this subject is constant debate in my country.

I am a student of Software Engineering at NUST, Pakistan.(A freshman) So basically, the students are divided into two factions; One with portfolios and the other with grades. Its actually a HUMAN vs a NERD competition respectively. The title says it all but
(I am personally with Portfolio but connecting with the experts is way more important) :)

Some of the common questions here are:

What do the employer prefers the most?

How can we survive with low grades.

Some basic and general guide on what to do after graduation. (How to interact with the companies, How to make your setup as a entrepreneur? etc.)

Comment: What on earth makes you believe this is an either/or proposition? The best bet is to do both.

Comment: A reputation and track record of *Smart* and *gets things done*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but in general, employers are looking for two things with fresh graduates:

1. **Skill set.** The theoretical knowledge relevant to the job: Knowing how to develop software with a specific tool in a specific language, for instance.
2. **The ability to execute.** Being able to take initiative and complete a task with an outcome that fulfills the requirements.

Grades are generally a result of being a good student. They indicate subject matter knowledge, which can be a proxy for the first item. They indicate at least a degree of ability with respect to execution, although in a very sterile, simple environment (studying for a test is an incredibly straightforward task compared to completing a software development project). They also indicate an ability to be molded, in the sense that good grades generally results from paying attention to instructions and understanding them.

A project portfolio, on the other hand, indicates a fairly high degree of both - you've got the theoretical skills to do projects, and you have actually done them.

In terms of what an employer *prefers* - that will depend on the employer, their culture, and the position. In some cases, you want someone who has the theory and can be molded/taught to operate within a big corporate machine (good grades) while as in other cases, you may need someone who can take initiative and finish stuff on their own without a ton of hand-holding (portfolio).

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep up a certain level of grades or you won't graduate.

As to how different employers look at grades vice projects, must prefer to have both. And the projects should be significant not just the slightly harder than  "Hello world".

In terms of which they will consider most important for a particular job that depends highly on the requirements of the job. I am going to be looking for a different skill set if the job is to create a new database engine than if it is to program embedded systems or build a generic website. Some of these jobs require more in depth theoretical knowledge than others and thus the grades are more important.

Others are looking for people who can quickly punch out project without the need for more than basic knowledge. They are going to care less about grades and more about projects.

It also depends on the culture of the company and the personality/background of the hiring official.  A manager who did not have a lot of formal education may think projects are more critical, a manager with a PhD is likely to go in the opposite direction.

A company that has a choice of top talent from the best schools is going to be pickier about both projects and grades than a company that is not as good to work for. When you have 1000 applicants and 2 positions, you can afford to be picky.

So the best way to be in consideration for the most jobs is to get good grades and do significant project work. The best way to do this is frankly to concentrate on grades during the semester and work on the projects during the school breaks.

And during your breaks, work on small to major projects that need the kind of thing you just learned about in the previous semester to solidify the knowledge. And work on something fairly major that uses tools, languages or techniques you are not going to cover in your classwork but which are important in the type of job you want to get after school.

Focus of the projects is important.  A game project is more important to me if I am hiring for a developer to create games, a phone app is more critical if I am hiring for a position that will be creating apps, etc.